# REST Api PATCH request doesn't update Int type values in database

Tags: c#, .net, rest, odata, azure-mobile-services

Rest API PATCH method is not updating the integer type values in the database. Below is the method i am using. When data is received GetChangedPropertyNames doesn't return integer attributes of the object as changed value.

```
public Task<OnsUser> PatchOnsUser(string id, Delta<OnsUser> patch)
    {
        var properties  = patch.GetChangedPropertyNames();
        object weightValue;
        patch.TryGetPropertyValue("Weight", out weightValue);
        Debug.WriteLine("Weight Value " + weightValue);
        return UpdateAsync(id, patch);
    }
```

Below is the object already present in the database.

```
{
    "BodyType": "Athletic",
    "Weight": 55,
    "Height": 165,
    "LastActive": "2018-01-22T12:59:43.943Z",
    "PunchLine": "PUnch Line new ",
    "Bio": "I Dont Know",
    "TotalRating": 1,
    "RatingSum": 5,
    "Age": 28,
    "Dob": "1990-03-04T14:00:00Z",
    "NickName": "Basit2",
    "MsalUniqueID": "faa7f68d-64f5-419f-97e9-8130bc53fcf5",
    "QbUserID": 41480556
}
```

See the below image, This is the data i sent via Postman, Note the value of Weight, Height, Punchline and bio.

[image]

This is what i receive in visual studio patch method. Note that only 5 values is considered as updated ones instead of 7. (It is considering NickName as updated value which i didn't changed)

[image]

Last thing, this is what is returned.

[image]

I am stuck on this issue from 3 days. I have no idea whats going wrong here. I am new in REST Api development. This issue has never happened before, in my previous project.

I can really use some help, Thanks

Comment: Your question appears to have nothing to do with REST, but with what is implemented in your method `UpdateAsync()` - code you haven't shared. How about you debug into it? Secondly, if a method is called `...Async()`, call it with an `await` and change the signature of `PatchOnsUser()` to `public async`.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst That is a library method in 'Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server'. I didn't write that code. This is the default implementation of the PATCH method when i created a controller this method was already there.
Last thing why does it update string and other values but not integer if there is issue with implementation.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I checked this issue on my side and it could work as expected on my side. Here are some details you could follow them.

**Model:**

```
public class Page: EntityData
{
    public int Color { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("weight")]
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public Point Offset { get; set; }
}
```

**Update operation:**

[image]

Per my understanding, the properties you sent to the mobile app backend would all be considered as the properties which would need to be updated.

**TEST:**

[image]

[image]

Moreover, my `GetChangedPropertyNames` method is under the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.5.5.1 package. Here are some related dependencies:

```html
<package id="Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server" version="1.1.157.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Authentication" version="1.1.157.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.CrossDomain" version="1.1.157.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Entity" version="1.1.157.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Home" version="1.1.157.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Login" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
<package id="Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Notifications" version="1.1.157.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Quickstart" version="1.1.157.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Tables" version="1.1.157.1" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Comment: Everything is working fine in my last project but not on this one. i was using v5.7.0 of Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData. I downgraded it and then tested it. Even then it is not working. I tried to add [JsonProperty("weight")] on attributes but still not working.

Comment: I just created the sample mobile app project to test this issue. Since you have mentioned that the previous version could work, but downgrade to the previous version did not work. Have you tried to create a new mobile app project to narrow this issue?